# Home networking with windows 7

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

We are currently running a home network using windows 7, where we have set up a homegroup etc for sharing files. We have a wireless network at home.

When I share files and my son downloads them, is this done through our home network as is, or does it use the internet to transfer the files. That is, when my son is downloading, is he getting them 'direct' from my machine through the router, or is it using the internet connection to do this? If the internet was down for whatever reason, would we still have a home network that worked?

We are using a wireless hub connected to cable internet (virgin media).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not use an outside connection. If your ISP were to drop service to you for some reason, the current arrangement would still work.

EDIT: This is, obviously, assuming that you are sharing the files via the Windows filesystem (homegroup/sharing settings) and not some internet based service like Dropbox, etc.

Comment: And so would this work as a basis to set up a fileserver at home?  No other equipment needed?

Comment: For very very basic purposes, yes - and I have done exactly that. Of course, keep in mind the limitations as compared to proper network file storage, but seems like you get the point.